# Where to find Wordpress directory on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2, php, wordpress

I installed Wordpress and every dependency on my Linux from the terminal. I ran into problems soon after as I could not upload files larger than 2MB. I edited the `php.ini` file, then I wanted to edit the `wp-config` file, all efforts to find the Wordpress directory locally have proved abortive. Does anyone know where the Wordpress directory can be, since it's not in the `/var/www/html/` path where it should be?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: If you installed this with one of the complete packages, then it's going to be somewhere in the `/opt` directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can find directories named `wordpress` with:

```sh
sudo find / -type d -name wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

My directory is in 'srv' folder when I followed standard wordpress instalment from the following link
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview

full path to the directory : /srv/www/wordpress